# Problems with authorization Camunda

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, camunda, camunda-modeler

The problem is that I am trying to add myself a rights check for users as all new users have admin access

Everything is set up via Docker. Build Camunda:

```
FROM camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-7.17.0

COPY production.yml /camunda/configuration/production.yml
```

.yml setup file:

```
camunda.bpm:
  webapp:
    csrf:
      enable-same-site-cookie: true
      same-site-cookie-option: STRICT
    header-security:
      hsts-disabled: false
      content-security-policy-value: base-uri 'self';
        default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
        img-src 'self' data:;
        block-all-mixed-content;
        form-action 'self';
        frame-ancestors 'none';
        object-src 'none';
        sandbox
        allow-forms
        allow-scripts
        allow-same-origin
        allow-popups
authorization:
    enabled: true
    user-id-claim: sub
    administratorGroupName: camunda-admin
    authorizationCheckRevokes: never
  generic-properties:
    properties:
      enable-password-policy: true
   admin-auth:
     enabled: true
     administrator-user-name: admin
     administrator-group-name: admins
```

The project is being built, but authorization still does not work, judging by the documentation, then all these settings are the maximum that needs to be done to make it work. Who set up authorization, please tell me what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your yaml uses incorrect spacing? The property is camunda.bpm.authorization.enabled.
In the yaml the authorization seems to be on the same level as camunda.bpm. Try to indent it 2 spaces.